# Pulling mercurial repo - getting 406

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, mercurial, redmine

I installed Redmine on an Ubuntu machine and have created a project which uses Mercurial as version control.

The Redmine application is the root of my Apache config. So `redmine.domain.com` goes directly to the Redmine installation where users log in, etc.

I created a repository in `/var/www/redmine/merc/`. When I set that as the root for the Redmine project, Redmine finds it and shows me files and versions under the repository tab.

What I'm trying to do is to pull this repository to my local machine running Windows 7. I installed TurtoiseHg and it went well. Now when I'm trying to pull from

```
http://redmine.domain.com/merc/
```

I get 404 not found. When I try to pull from

```
http://redmine.domain.com/projects/project1/repository
```

I get 406 command aborted!

How am I supposed to set this up? I looked in Apache's config files but I didn't see anything that would suggest that external requests be aborted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, Redmine does not let you push and pull using Mercurial — you need to configure that in parallel. It's not hard to configure the `hgweb` (Fast)CGI script we supply. We have [information in the wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories) and I found a [nice blog post](http://hadoken.free.fr/blog/?p=7) explaining how to install both Redmine and Mercurial on Fedora 13. I hope that helps you along.